# How to retrieve a username from a simple JavaScript login form?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, session-cookies

I have a simple javascript login form on the index.html page, if succesful the users is directed to main.html, I would like to display their username in the header on this page. Is it possible to get form the cookies session of through local storage?

```
  <form name="loginform" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="main.html" method="post">
      <label>User name</label>
      <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="username"> 
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button"/>
  </form>

  <script>
      function validateForm() {
          var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
          var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
          var username = "username"; 
          var password = "password";
          if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
            alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
            return false;
         }
      }
  </script>
```

#### Main.html

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
       var name = localStorage.getItem('username');
       if (name != "undefined" || name != "null") {
       document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "!";
       } else
       document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Hello!";
    }
   </script>

   <span id="welcomeMessage"></span>
```

This currently return 'null' as i dont know how to set the localstorage on the index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can set the username:

```
    window.localStorage.setItem('username',username);
```

Then access it on any page:

```
   window.localStorage.getItem('username');
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include the main.html page but I cant understand how to window.localStorage.setItem('username',username); on the index.html and then the main.html will know where to get it from...

Comment: You set the localStorage in your function, after you declare your username variable. Then $("#"welcomeMessage").text(window.localStorage.getItem("username"));